# Does nanoc support nested partials?

Tags: nested, partial, nanoc

I am using partials in nanoc, and I was wondering if it's possible to nest partials in nanoc. In other words, can I have a partial within a partial?

When I tested this, the site compiled, but the nested partial did not display.

I'm using the Partials implementation described in this stackoverflow post: [Must include files in nanoc always be in the layouts folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367811/must-include-files-in-nanoc-always-be-in-the-layouts-folder)

While nested partials are not required for what we're trying to do, I was just wondering if this is possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use nested partials with nanoc. Here's a way to demonstrate this:

1. Create a new site using nanoc.
2. From within the site directory, create the folder `content/partials`.
3. Create the "outer" and "inner" partial content. In the file `content/partials/_outer.html`, place:

   ```
   <p>This is the outer partial.</p>

   <p><%= @items['/partials/_inner/'].compiled_content %></p>
   ```

   And in the file `content/partials/_inner.html`:

   ```
   This is the inner partial.
   ```

   Note that we now have one partial including the contents of another.
4. Edit the main page, `content/index.html`, so it embeds the outer partial:

   ```
   <h1>A Brand New nanoc Site</h1>

   <%= @items['/partials/_outer/'].compiled_content %>
   ```
5. Add these rules to `Rules` *above* the ones already present:

   ```
   # Filter but do not lay-out partial content
   compile '/partials/*' do
     filter :erb
   end

   # Do not output partials; they are only ever embedded in other content
   route '/partials/*' do
     nil
   end
   ```
6. Now generate the site with `nanoc compile`. When you view it you'll see the inner partial content nested inside the outer partial content, nested inside the main page, like this:

   ## A Brand New nanoc Site

   This is the outer partial.

   This is the inner partial.

Comment: my previously-working Nanoc partials just stopped compiling, either with the older `<%= @items['/_inc/filename/'].compiled_content %>`
or with the newer wildcard path: `['/_inc/filename.*']`